# ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small with EXTRACT function

Tags: oracle, plsql, precision, oracle12c

I faced strange issue with `EXTRACT` function when trying to get the seconds interval of 8-12 hours.

This is tested with Oracle 12.2
Example:
https://rextester.com/ZMR79428

```sql
declare 
  start_time_ TIMESTAMP;  
  exect_time_ NUMBER;  
begin
start_time_ := SYSDATE- 1/3;  -- 8 hours, error is for SYSDATE- 1/2
exect_time_ := extract(day from ((sysdate- start_time_)*86400));
dbms_output.put_line(exect_time_);
end;
```

I can't see what wrong I've done to get the *leading precision of the interval is too small* error in this code. It worked for all other scenarios.
Eg: `SYSDATE -1/4` works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the seconds interval of 8-12 hours"?

Comment: To be exact, this is what I'm trying to do. `select extract(day from ((systimestamp - (systimestamp -1/3))*86400)) from dual`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The `start_time_` variable is declared as a `TIMESTAMP` so `SYSDATE - 1/3` is implicitly cast from a `DATE` data type to a `TIMESTAMP` and then if you do `SYSDATE - start_time_` you have `DATE - TIMESTAMP` which will result in another implicit cast of the left operand from `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP` and the result will be an `INTERVAL`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You can use `EXTRACT( DAY FROM INTERVAL '8' HOUR' )` and the output will just be zero ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e5b8d9798e37ffc9c67e5db6fe1bbe6)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract two `DATE` data type values you get a `NUMBER` representing the number of (fractional) days between the two values. If you subtract two `TIMESTAMP` data type values you get an `INTERVAL` data type.

So your answer could simply be:

```sql
declare 
  start_time_ DATE   := SYSDATE- 1/3;
  exect_time_ NUMBER;  
begin
  exect_time_ := ( sysdate - start_time_ ) *86400;
  dbms_output.put_line( exect_time_ );
end;
/
```

Which outputs: `28800`

Your problem is that you are multiplying by `86400` inside the `EXTRACT` function rather than outside; so `SYSDATE - start_time_` gives `INTERVAL '8' HOUR` and then you are multiplying by `86400` and `INTERVAL '8' HOUR * 86400` would give a value of  `INTERVAL '28800' DAY` which does not fit into the default precision of an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type (and would give you the wrong answer anyway).

What you would want (if you really want to use `TIMESTAMP`s) is:

```sql
declare 
  start_time_ TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP - 1/3;
  difference  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := SYSTIMESTAMP - start_time_;
  exect_time_ NUMBER;  
begin
  exect_time_ := EXTRACT( DAY    FROM difference ) * 24 * 60 * 60
               + EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM difference )      * 60 * 60
               + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM difference )           * 60
               + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM difference );
  dbms_output.put_line( exect_time_ );
end;
/
```

Which outputs something like `28800.246382` (as there is a fraction of a second between the two `SYSTIMESTAMP` calls).

or, if you do not care about fractional seconds then:

```sql
declare 
  start_time_ TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP- 1/3;
  exect_time_ NUMBER;  
begin
  exect_time_ := ( SYSDATE - CAST( start_time_ AS DATE ) ) * 86400;
  dbms_output.put_line( exect_time_ );
end;
/
```

Which outputs `28800`.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3dccdb40f8146e9caf2aec6588c54e3c)

---

> what I don't get is why it gives error

It is a strange error; the code below tests various cases:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE test_case IS RECORD(
    units      VARCHAR2(20),
    difference INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
    multiplier NUMBER(8,0)
  );
  TYPE test_case_list IS TABLE OF test_case;

  FUNCTION createTestCase(
    units      VARCHAR2,
    difference INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
    multiplier NUMBER
  ) RETURN test_case;

  test_cases test_case_list := test_case_list(
    createTestCase( 'SECOND',               INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 24 * 60 * 60 ),
    createTestCase( 'SECOND PLUS A LITTLE', INTERVAL '1' SECOND + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND, 24 * 60 * 60 ),
    createTestCase( 'MINUTE',               INTERVAL '1' MINUTE, 24 * 60 ),
    createTestCase( 'MINUTE PLUS A LITTLE', INTERVAL '1' MINUTE + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND, 24 * 60 ),
    createTestCase( 'HOUR',                 INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 24 ),
    createTestCase( 'HOUR PLUS A LITTLE',   INTERVAL '1' HOUR + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND, 24 ),
    createTestCase( 'DAY',                  INTERVAL '1' DAY, 1 ),
    createTestCase( 'DAY PLUS A LITTLE',    INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND, 1 )
  );

  FUNCTION createTestCase(
    units      VARCHAR2,
    difference INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
    multiplier NUMBER
  ) RETURN test_case
  IS
    tc test_case;
  BEGIN
    tc.units      := units;
    tc.difference := difference;
    tc.multiplier := multiplier;
    RETURN tc;
  END;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. test_cases.COUNT LOOP
    BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( test_cases(i).units );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( test_cases(i).difference * test_cases(i).multiplier * 100000 );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( (SYSTIMESTAMP + test_cases(i).difference - SYSTIMESTAMP) * test_cases(i).multiplier * 10000 );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( (SYSTIMESTAMP + test_cases(i).difference - SYSTIMESTAMP) * test_cases(i).multiplier * 100000 );
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SQLERRM );
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

and outputs:

> ```
> SECOND
> +000100000 00:00:00.000000000
> +000009999 21:21:36.000000000
> ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
> SECOND PLUS A LITTLE
> +000100100 00:00:00.000000000
> +000010009 22:33:36.000000000
> +000100099 19:12:00.000000000
> MINUTE
> +000100000 00:00:00.000000000
> +000009999 23:59:31.200000000
> ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
> MINUTE PLUS A LITTLE
> +000100001 16:00:00.000000000
> +000010000 03:59:02.400000000
> +000100001 15:55:12.000000000
> HOUR
> +000100000 00:00:00.000000000
> +000009999 23:59:59.280000000
> ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
> HOUR PLUS A LITTLE
> +000100000 00:40:00.000000000
> +000010000 00:03:59.040000000
> +000100000 00:39:55.200000000
> DAY
> +000100000 00:00:00.000000000
> +000009999 23:59:59.970000000
> ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
> DAY PLUS A LITTLE
> +000100000 00:01:40.000000000
> +000010000 00:00:09.960000000
> +000100000 00:01:39.800000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=35dced6c92a96b1f4d426f88188f3767)*

- Using `INTERVAL` directly in each test case works.
- When you force the PL/SQL engine to work out `SYSTIMESTAMP + an_interval - SYSTIMESTAMP` then it must call the `SYSTIMESTAMP` function twice (which means that there is a few fractions of a second difference between the values) and the test cases fail.
- When you add a tiny amount of time to the interval then the test cases all pass again suggesting that an Interval with a different precision has resulted from the calculation. (This is not intended to be a hacky solution, just an interesting side-note).
- [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=11281a3f8a158d5e7f1bbb027f07c79d) shows that it only occurs in the PL/SQL scope; if you run the same statements in SQL statements then there are no exceptions.

There is probably a bug but it would require diving into the precision of the data-types returned when dynamically generating intervals from `SYSTIMESTAMP` to work out how exactly it is occurring; and, beyond being able to make a bug report to Oracle (which they might fix in a later version), it isn't going make your solution any more viable.

However, that's tangential to the solution; don't multiply your `INTERVAL` by `86400`; you should be using `EXTRACT` multiple times with `DAY`, `HOUR`, `MINUTE` and `SECOND` respective arguments and converting the returned values of each to seconds and adding them or, alternatively, using `CAST` to convert back to use `DATE` arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's messy code but what I don't get is why it gives error only between `SYSDATE - 1/3` and `SYSDATE - 1/2`.  If we use put `SYSDATE - 1` it gets `INTERVAL 86400` but works fine

Comment: Thanks @MT0 for the comprehensive explanation. This error was easily solved by using an alternate for `EXTRACT` but it was curios when oracle behaves strange 

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is because of the limitation of the too-large numbers in intervals.

Actually, the Issue is with the multiplication.

If you execute it without or with a small multiplier than you will get an answer.

```
SQL> select extract(day from ((systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1/3)))) from dual ;

EXTRACT(DAYFROM((SYSTIMESTAMP-(SYSTIMESTAMP-1/3))))
---------------------------------------------------
                                                  0

SQL> select extract(day from ((systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1/3))*8640)) from dual ;

EXTRACT(DAYFROM((SYSTIMESTAMP-(SYSTIMESTAMP-1/3))*8640))
--------------------------------------------------------
                                                    2880

SQL> select extract(day from ((systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1/3))*86400)) from dual ;
select extract(day from ((systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1/3))*86400)) from dual
                                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small


SQL>
```

Whatever you are doing with this number, you need to think of different logic as multiplication on the timestamp column is not recommended.

Cheers!!